# TSharedPtr vs. UOBJECT(), pros and cons?

Tags: c++, unreal

In Unreal Engine C++, I'm trying to weigh whether it's better to use TSharedPtrs or UOBJECTS() as a general strategy.

- Which uses more memory?
- Which has higher CPU overhead?
- Thread safety options?

In the project currently, TSharedPtrs are used for everything that's pure data, and UOBJECTs are used for anything that may need to be handled by Blueprints.

My bias is that I'd prefer to do everything with UOBJECTs if they're equal.

- I prefer garbage collection over ref-counting, because it's less babysitting and ceremony.
- Ref-counting also causes memory management to happen immediately, which has caused UI hiccups on other projects, whereas garbage collection tends to happen at a different time than the user interaction.
- I prefer to do everything with a single hammer and not mix very different approaches.

Comment: They are different tools for different needs. `UOBJECT` only works for classes derived from `UObject` (and should also be used with [`TObjectPtr`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/TObjectPtr/)) while `TSharedPtr` works for all kinds of objects.

Comment: Well, "it depends" is not a real answer. If I made everything UOBJECTs that it would work for "all kinds of objects", so that argument doesn't hold. I really want an actual weighing of differences.

Comment: Also when it comes to frame-rate hiccups, both reference counting and tracing GC are equally poor choices.

Comment: You can't use `TSharedPtr` with `UObject`'s

Comment: Yes, I know that I can't use TSharedPtr with a UObject, they're different memory management animals.

Comment: About frame-rate hiccups, this is not true for a non-real-time app. This app depends on user interaction, and in another app, our shared-ptr strategy has backfired, because ALL processing happens within a millisecond of the user interacting, causing constant freezes. Garbage collection happens later when the user is not clicking, so there isn't the same sense of click-sluggishness.

Comment: So, what the question then? For all `UObject`'s you have to use GC, for the rest - it's really up to you. If you need to know what the difference between reference counting and GC then it was covered already.

Comment: The question is exactly as stated. What is the memory and CPU overhead and thread safety differences?

Comment: It's the million dollar question that nobody seems willing to answer on any forum.

Comment: The memory and CPU overhead of tracing GC is always larger than that of reference counting, simply due to implementation complexity. Reference-counting only adds a control block with 2 (atomic) integers, GC needs to keep track of all references to objects (and then follow them during the marking phase)

Comment: But my guess is that UOBJECTs are heavier than TSharedPtrs, because TSharedPtrs only have to do ref-counting. UOBJECTs also have to do ref-counting, but also a whole lot of other stuff to manage memory recovery.

Comment: Probably that's because you don't really ask any question here. What you ask is to compare GC and reference counting. There are plenty material about that and it's impossible to answer within SO answer format.

Comment: Hi UnholySheep, thanks, that's a very good answer.

Comment: Michael, no, the question is stated plainly as three bullet points. And no, there is not plenty of material regarding Unreal GC versus ref-counting. I have spent a full day on Google trying to answer this for Unreal.

Comment: For a more detailed discussion of the topic you'd need to consult specialized literature, such as ["The Garbage Collection Handbook"](http://gchandbook.org/)

Comment: But again, a general GC handbook is not helpful, because it may know nothing about how Unreal does GC.

Comment: Unreal GC is a standard mark-and-sweep GC - the only difference is that it is restricted to run at specific time intervals

Comment: The closest I've gotten to an answer in the Unreal forum has been (a) one person mentioning that after moving a lot of stuff to TSharedPtrs, they only gained a few percent of performance, but fixing an algorithm gained 50% performance, so to not worry. (b) Someone comments that if you look at the engine source, Epic uses UOBJECTs for tons of things that are pure data, indicating that Epic thinks that UOBJECTs are performant. This is the kind of stuff that makes me wonder if TSharedPtrs are worth the extra hazzle as a general strategy.

Comment: I generally try to avoid both options. For pure data it mainly doesn't matter, as most of it is only destroyed at the end of a level/game. Anything that gets created during a level I'd try to manually manage anyway, causes way less performance issues than either option. GC works okay enough on powerful machines, but once you get to more resource constrained devices it can quickly become a bottleneck

Comment: Hi Unholysheep, thank you for the field experience. I tend to only do manual allocations when it's fully contained within a class and I can deallocate in the destructor. But I will heed the advice that TSharedPtrs only have one job of ref-counting, where UOBJECTs have much more that needs to be done. If you'll summarize your opinions in an answer, I'm happy to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a general level the differences are as follow:

`TSharedPtr` allocates an additional "control block" containing 2 integers (one for tracking strong references, one for tracking weak references) - these integer operations can be performed atomically or not (based on a template parameter) depending whether thread-safety is required. Any adding or subtracting of the count happens immediately, making the performance impact easily trackable. However, as all operations happen immediately, object deletion may happen in the middle of a critical section.

`UObject`s do not keep track of references themselves, however the garbage collector itself needs to keep track of all references. During a marking phase it then has to traverse these references to figure out which objects are still referenced and which can be safely collected. The performance impact is trickier to measure, as it can vary more heavily depending on amount of tracked objects and registered references (and have more cache misses from following references) - although generally speaking memory requirements are higher than for reference counting. Unreal Engine additionally restricts the GC to only run in specific intervals (by default every 60ms), which should prevent it happening during a critical section of code execution.

Therefore making a general rule of thumb is trickier, as the usage can heavily impact performance. Data is generally only loaded once and unloaded at level/game end, making any difference neglible. For the utmost performance optimization avoiding both options is usually the best choice, but can be trickier to implement (as it requires more careful thought about how the code is used)

---

Also worth noting is that tracing GC can easier become a bottleneck on memory constrained devices (e.g.: mobile), due to less powerful hardware. Since it's not possible to completely avoid using `UObject`s in Unreal, this sometimes requires manually creating "object pools" to avoid excessive GC pauses